# scala spark paritions: understanding the output

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am running spark and scala. What is the meaning of the line that i get when i run `rawblocks.partitions.length`? My linkage folder had 10 files.

1. what does `res1` and `Int` stand for?
2. Also is there a place where i
   can find official documentation for spark methods? For example i
   want to see details of `textFile`.

   spark version 1.6.1

   ```
   Using Scala version 2.10.5 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_65)

   scala> val rawblocks=sc.textFile("linkage")
   rawblocks: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = linkage MapPartitionsRDD[3] at textFile at <console>:27

   scala> rawblocks.partitions.length
   res1: Int = 10
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The `res1` and `Int` are not special to Spark: `res1` is a name given in **Scala REPL** (shell) to **unnamed values** - results are numerated (starting from zero), for example:

   ```
   scala> 10
   res0: Int = 10

   scala> "hello"
   res1: String = hello
   ```

   This should also give you a clue about `Int` - it's the inferred **type** of this value (Scala's `Int` is somewhat equivalent to Java's `Integer`).
2. Spark API: here's the documentation for the two primary entry points of Spark-core: [SparkContext](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.html), [RDD](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.html)